# "" DELPHI : E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical ""

Tags: delphi

So i'm getting this error message, can someone help me, already tried a lot of google answers :p nothing worked.

**ctrl+shift+space result on ReadProcessMemory**

```
**Parameters** 
hProcess System.Cardinal 
IpBaseAddress System.Pointer 
IpBuffer System.Pointer 
nSize System.Cardinal 
IpNumberOfBytesRead System.Cardinal 
**Returns** 
System.Boolean
```

**Ptr Function:**

```
Ptr Function: function Ptr(Value: Integer): Pointer;
```

**Variables**

```
var 
  Form1: TForm1; 
  PH : THandle; 
  PID, ThID: DWORD; 
  H : THandle;

function Ptr(Value: Integer): Pointer;
```

---

**Function**

```
function LerInt(Address: Integer): Integer;
var
  value:integer;
  ler:dword;
begin
  H := FindWindow(nil, 'Something Here :)');
  ThID := GetWindowThreadProcessID(H, @PID);
  PH := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
  ReadProcessMemory(PH, Ptr(Address), @value, 4, ler); // THIS LINE
  Result:=value;
end;
```

Comment: It means that you put argument of wrong type to one of functions here (the one to which compiler points you). Point is: if you have procedure (i: Integer), you can call it passing byte, shortint, Word, Integer after all and compiler will cast you argument to the type procedure needs. But if you have procedure (var i: Integer), you must pass STRICTLY Integer and nothing more. So, look exact types of arguments and compare with what you write here.

Comment: It would be easy to answer exactly what argument here is wrong, if you provided us with exact line where this error arised and types of variables we don't know as H, ThID, PH. Telepaths are on their way of course, but please don't rely on them too much.

Comment: The compiler tells you **exactly** what line is causing the problem, and using Code Insight (Ctrl+Shift+Space between the function parameter parens) tell you **exactly** what the datatype is that is expected for each parameter. As you've not bothered to either include the line number for the error or indicate which line is the issue, use the information I just gave you to figure it out yourself. :-) IOW, there's absolutely no reason for you not to identify the specific problem area for us, since it's right on your screen in front of you.

Comment: You've also not bothered to indicate what some of the variable types are that you're using (eg., H, ThID, PH, PID). If you want help from us, **give us the information you already have**. You're asking for free help from us to solve a problem you're having - you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Comment: Another important missing piece is what `Ptr` is. Your lack of error checking is going to come back to haunt you. Win32 API calls won't throw exceptions. You have to check for errors. I say this at least 10 times a day.

Comment: Please don't ask the question in comments. Use question edits. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, is this better ? i'm new here

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is a lot better.

Comment: @David: Yep. I misread, and got the type for `value` instead. Mea culpa. Deleting the comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `ler` is the wrong type. It must be `SIZE_T`.

Other comments:

1. You don't need a function to convert an integer to a pointer. Just cast it with `Pointer(address)`. Note though that you will encounter pointer truncation problems if you ever pass this code through the 64 bit compiler.
2. You do not check for errors in any of your API calls. Please check for errors.

Comment: Omg, how stupid am i :p Thanks it worked! And thanks all for the help and tips.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which Delphi version declares the last parameter to `ReadProcessMemory` as `SIZE_T`? (Upvoting your answer; just asking.)

Comment: @ken. That is to be compatible with the 64 bit compiler, I think.

Comment: XE has DWORD so yes, it must have been XE2

Comment: @LURD: Seatlle declares it as `NativeUInt`; 2007 declares it as `Cardinal`. It does appear to be XE2 (in RAD Studio\12.0\Source\Rtl\Win\Windows.pas) Or is that XE3? No matter now, anyway. Thanks.